# Value won't assign in Yacc outside of Token

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

In Yacc I've written a parser that should recognize a number or string and assign it to a `NAME` token I've created. It seems to be working in that the variables get assigned and if I print their values they're correct. However, once Yacc moves to the next token, the values are wiped as if the variables were never assigned to. The rule `NAME '=' NAME` is where it's assigned within the rule but no where else. This is only an issue when copying one `NAME` / variable's value to another. At the bottom is a photo of what I'm referring to and this is my code:

## Simple.y

```
%{
    #include "ch3hdr.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    int yylex(void);
    void yyerror(char *);
%}

%union {
    char* str;
    double dval;
    struct symtab *symp;
}

%token <symp> NAME
%token <dval> NUMBER
%token <str>  STRING
%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc UMINUS

%type <dval> numexpr
%type <str>  strexpr
%%

statement_list: statement '\n'
    |       statement_list statement '\n'
    ;

statement:  NAME '=' numexpr    { $1->num = $3; $1->type = NUM; }
    |       NAME '=' strexpr    { $1->str = $3; $1->type = STR; }
    |       NAME '=' NAME       { 
                                    $1 = $3;

                                    switch($3->type)
                                    {
                                        case NUM: 
                                        {  
                                            $1->num = $3->num; 
                                            $1->type = NUM; 
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        case STR:
                                        {
                                            $1->str = $3->str;
                                            $1->type = STR;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        default:  yyerror("Declaration invalid\n"); break;
                                    }
                                }
    |       NAME                { 
                                    switch($1->type)
                                    {
                                        case NUM: fprintf(stderr, "num = %g\n", $1->num); break;
                                        case STR: fprintf(stderr, "str = %s\n", $1->str); break;
                                        default:  fprintf(stderr, "var not defined %g\n", $1->num); break;
                                    }
                                }
    |       numexpr             { fprintf(stderr, "numexpr = %g\n", $1); }
    |       strexpr             { fprintf(stderr, "strexpr = %s\n", $1); }         
    ;

numexpr:    numexpr '+' numexpr   { $$ = $1 + $3; // where $1 is first entered token
                                                        // $3 is next token after "="
                                        }
    |       numexpr '-' numexpr   { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    |       numexpr '*' numexpr   { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    |       numexpr '/' numexpr   
                { 
                    if($3 == 0.0)
                        yyerror("divide by zero");
                    else
                        $$ = $1 / $3;
                }
    |       '-' numexpr %prec UMINUS { $$ = -$2; }
    |       '(' numexpr ')'          { $$ = $2; }
    |       NUMBER                   
    |       NAME '(' numexpr ')' { $$ = ($1->funcptr)($3); }
    ;

strexpr:    STRING 
    ;
%% 

void yyerror(char *str)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %s", str);
}

struct symtab *symlook(char *s) {
    char *p;
    struct symtab *sp;

    for(sp = symtab; sp < &symtab[NSYMS]; sp++) {
        /* is it already here? */
        if(sp->name && !strcmp(sp->name, s))
            return sp;
        if(!sp->name) { /* is it free */
            sp->name = strdup(s);
            return sp; 
        }
        /* otherwise continue to next */
    }
    yyerror("Too many symbols");
    exit(1);    /* cannot continue */
} /* symlook */

void addfunc(char *name, double (*func)())
{
    struct symtab *sp = symlook(name);
    sp->funcptr = func;
}

int main() {
    extern double sqrt(), exp(), log();

    addfunc("sqrt", sqrt);
    addfunc("exp", exp);
    addfunc("log", log);

    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

## Simple.l

```
%{
#include "simple.tab.h"
#include "ch3hdr.h"
#include <math.h>
%}

%%

([0-9]+|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?) {
    yylval.dval = atof(yytext); 
    return NUMBER; 
    }

[ \t] ;  /* ignore whitespace */
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*   { 
        yylval.symp = symlook(yytext);
        return NAME; 
    }

\"[^"\n]*["\n] { 
        yylval.str = yytext;
        return STRING; 
    }

"$"   return 0; /* logical EOF */
\n    |
.     return yytext[0];
%%
```

## ch3hdr.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NSYMS 20

typedef enum 
{
    NUM = 1,
    STR = 2
} TYPE;

struct symtab
{
    char *name;
    // ptr to C function to call if this entry is a fucntion name
    double (*funcptr)();
    double value;

    double num;
    char*  str;

    TYPE type;

} symtab[NSYMS];

struct symtab *symlook();
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know that was not allowed, I thought it would help elaborate but I'll remove it now.

Comment: Posting images is ok if required, but that was just text. Any problem copy/pasting?

Comment: I just figured it would be easier to show the picture than to explain it in text. I think the post is probably clear enough at this time for someone to understand it but if someone needs me to elaborate I'll copy and paste the terminal output.

Comment: The image did only contain text! Think about the last comments!

Comment: Posting images of text is (a) redundant (b) a waste of your time and (c) a waste of our bandwidth, and (d) makes it impossible to copy/paste those parts of your question into answers. Post the *text.*

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the lexer rule:

```
yylval.str = yytext;
```

This just copies a pointer, to data that will get overwritten some time in the future. You need to copy the data:

```
yylval.str = strdup(yytext);
```

And this will create a memory leak unless you issue a corresponding `free()` as soon as you are finished with it, some time in the parse phase or later.

Comment: Thank you for being more specific, although that didn't fix my problem I think I understand the problem better now.

Comment: In that case you have another problem. This fixes the problem you described.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning `yytext` in `Simple.l`, presuming its value will remain the same.  It will not, since it is an internal value of the lexer, and will be updated each time `yylex` is called.

This chunk from the lexer is what I see:

```
\"[^"\n]*["\n] { 
        yylval.str = yytext;
        return STRING; 
    }
```

In the yacc grammar, the value is used without copying, e.g.,

```
                                    case STR:
                                    {
                                        $1->str = $3->str;
                                        $1->type = STR;
                                        break;
                                    }
```

This has come up occasionally, but the last time I answered it (in *[Bison token is rest of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34481544/4518274)*), I found no suitable accepted answer to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: So the issue is in my "symlook()" method and it's returning the wrong value there?

Comment: @BennetLeff No, the problem is that you are returning `yytext` in `Simple.l,` as he said.